# redhat yum install - GPG key retrieval failed

Tags: yum

I was trying to yum install etckeeper on a Linux box. Details are as following.

the installation failed at key retrieval.

I am wondering why the key file is addressed as file:///etc/pki/. Isn't the key files should be retrieved via http?

```
[me@linux ~]$ sudo yum install etckeeper
[sudo] password for me: 
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package etckeeper.noarch 0:1.4-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================
Package                  Arch                  Version                    Repository             Size
=====================================================================================================
Installing:
 etckeeper                noarch                1.4-1.el6                  epel                   38 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================
 Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 38 k
Installed size: 61 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6


GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to import manually

```
# rpm --import http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also simply install with the command 
    `yum install --nogpgcheck {packagename}`

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the epel-release package first in order to get GPG-Keys installed:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```